# Copy specific index value of array to another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to copy a specific values at specific index from one array to another like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if ([subID[i]  isEqual: @"0"]) {
            NSLog(@"state : %@",arrayTempState[i]);
            NSString *str = arrayTempState[i];
           [arrayState addObject:str];
            NSLog(@"%@",arrayState[i]);

 }
```

`arrayState` is `NSMutableArray` and `arrayTempState` is `NSArray`

but `arrayState` is null every time.

I tried `arrayState[i] = arrayTempState[i];` but it did not work.

Comment: Have you alloc/init arrayState?

Comment: It is unlikely that `i` will be the correct index in `arrayState` since you are conditionally adding values, so there will be fewer elements.

Comment: Yes it solved now, because it was not allocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayState` was not initialised that is why it couldn't store the value.

Answer (score 0):

plz try this

```
arrayState = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if ([subID[i]  isEqual: @"0"]) {
            NSLog(@"state : %@",arrayTempState[i]);
            NSString *str = arrayTempState[i];
           [arrayState addObject:str];
            NSLog(@"%@",arrayState[i]);

 }
```